# Grub2 does not detect my wifi slax OS

Tags: linux, grub2, dual-boot, boot-loader, multiboot

I have installed wifi slax OS from a usb on a partition along side with windows 10 and the installation process install also grub2 when finished I reboot and grub2 show only windows 10 loader.
So, how I can list all available OS to boot?

my grup.cfg file contains:

---

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos7'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  68c96891-4e12-46ff-a9c5-b8c46a361698
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 68c96891-4e12-46ff-a9c5-b8c46a361698
fi
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/dejavusansmono.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos7'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  68c96891-4e12-46ff-a9c5-b8c46a361698
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 68c96891-4e12-46ff-a9c5-b8c46a361698
fi
insmod gfxmenu
loadfont ($root)/boot/grub/themes/Wifislax/Sans-10.pf2
loadfont ($root)/boot/grub/themes/Wifislax/Sans-12.pf2
loadfont ($root)/boot/grub/themes/Wifislax/Sans-14.pf2
insmod png
set theme=($root)/boot/grub/themes/Wifislax/theme.txt
export theme
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
}
set linux_gfx_mode=
export linux_gfx_mode

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-EC023C1B023BE96A' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  EC023C1B023BE96A
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root EC023C1B023BE96A
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

---

Comment: Where's the installation process that you followed?

Comment: From wifi slax live version a system script called install wifi slax

Comment: Alright, so what's in your /boot/grub/grub.cfg?

Comment: How can I know it?

Comment: You can boot from the live CD/USB, mount the filesystem where you installed WifiSlax, and then look at the file.

Comment: question edited to contains the grup.cfg file contents

Answer (score 0):

Something must have gone wrong with the installation because you don't have a  menu entry for Linux. You can probably fix it manually:

1. Boot the Live CD/USB.
2. Mount the root partition again.
3. Bind-mount the /boot directory inside the root partition: `mount --bind /WHERE/EVER/YOU/MOUNTED/ROOT/PARTITION/boot /boot`
4. Run `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Then, check grub.cfg again; it should have an menu entry(ies) for Linux. If not, maybe you don't have any kernels in /boot; which would mean the installer probably failed.

Comment: the mount operation was successfull executed but the second gives this error   "  /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `overlay'. "

Comment: Yeah, that's going to be a pain to fix from the Live CD. Add to your question the files under /boot. Once mounted you can do `find WHATEVER_MOUNT_POINT_IS/boot`. My idea is to essentially boot from the HD, tell GRUB about the kernel so it can boot it, and then once booted you can do the `grub-mkconfig` part.